# Moving the content of an DIV to another window with JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make an "Print product" feature on my ecommerce site and the print part i already figured it out ... windows.print

My problem is that I want to copy the entire content of DIV where I have all product specifications and photos to another window which after I can print it.

I have a link **Print this product** which when clicked, JQUERY must create the new window and also copy the entire product's DIV to this new window.

I have seen several approaches here and it only confused me so that's why I am posting this here.

Can someone please explain me with an example how to solve my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think that this plugin of jquery might help you.

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Comment: In the meantime I found myself this library and its fantastic... It does everything for you.

Answer (score 4):

Just get the content and set it in the new place:

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.body.innerHTML = window.document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KpWMv/1/)